# Create an Empty List and push data in an Iteration using Robot Framework

Tags: selenium, pycharm, robotframework, selenium2library, robotframework-ide

I need to make a collection which is populated in a loop. So, I need a global collection and I need to use that collection variable in For Loop using Robot Framework.

Kindly look at the code

```
*** Settings ***
Library    Selenium2Library
Library    Collections

*** Keywords ***
Parent Routine
    ${ScoreList} ???
    : For    ${i}     IN RANGE    1    5
    \    Append To List    ${ScoreList}    ${i}
    #\    Some other manipulation


*** Test Cases ***
Sample Test Case
    [Documentation]   Simple test for Collection
    Parent Routine
```

I referred the http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Collections.html

Kindly assist me how to achieve this.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In your code you missed the declaration, in other words you need to create a List using the keyword `Create List`

To declare a List you need to use the following code

```
@{ScoreList}=    Create List
```

The Complete Code is

```
*** Settings ***
Library    Selenium2Library
Library    Collections

*** Keywords ***
Parent Routine
    @{ScoreList}=    Create List
    : For    ${i}     IN RANGE    1    5
    \    Append To List    ${ScoreList}    ${i}
    #\    Some other manipulation
    :FOR  ${item}  IN  @{ScoreList}
    \    log to console    ${item}


*** Test Cases ***
Sample Test Case
    [Documentation]   Simple test for Collection
    Parent Routine
```